# A mismatch between 'flags' and 'comment flags'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

Since I've been using the >10k tools more often recently (on SO), I've noticed that the 'flags' count seems to represent the number of flagged comments ('2'), while the 'comment flags' count the number of flags ('3'):

[image]

This disparity isn't a huge problem, or anything, but it seems a strange inconsistency between the two numbers. Especially since, so far as I can tell, there's no real reason for the 'comment Flags' count, as the number of flags per comment is shown besides the comment, and the number of comments that have attracted flags is shown at the top.

I'm not sure if I'm posting this more as an unnecessary replication of information (UI bug) or a presentation bug due to the disparity itself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the number on the flag tab is the number of posts on the flag list. So if you have just one post with many flagged comments, the tab will still show "1".

Comment: Which makes sense; the part that confuses me is the sum of all flags (the 3, above), as I can't see the purpose of it. Still, I'll accept this answer as the 'bug' is 'bydesign.'